# Blazor WebAssembly third party api

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am going to develop a Blazor application in WASM, I have to call a third party API which is not written in .net. The api is not on the same server as the WASM application and has CORS enabled. My question is:

I create the Blazor WASM application without .net core hosting and call the api directly using httpclient or I create it hosted in .net core and call the api using the controllers, if I use this approach I can protect the controllers with the token provided by the API from third parties? Which should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When CORS is configured correctly you should be able to call it directly from Blazor WebAssembly.